# How to call Javascript function from another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Yes, I have both functions included in html. I know the ordering matters. What I'm confused about is the way that the JS functions are set up, and I don't know the right way to call the function I want.

For example, I have a `Items.js`, in which I show some things on the screen, but I want to hide all of those items when the user activates something in a `Phone.js`

How `Items.js` is set up:

```
Items = function()
{
    this.stop = function()
    {
       // Items are hidden
       $(this.ButtonDiv).hide();
       $(this.CounterDiv).hide();
    }
}
```

Now how do I call the stop function from `Phone.js`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather that declaring Items as a function try this:

```
var Items = {
    stop: function() {
        // Items are hidden
       $(this.ButtonDiv).hide();
       $(this.CounterDiv).hide();
    }
}
```

And call the function like: `Items.stop();`

Answer (score 2):

`Items.js` must be loaded first.  Inside `Phone.js` you can call the function as:

```
Items.stop();
```

If that doesn't work (though I think it should), create a class instance of `Items()` first and then call the `stop()` method:

```
var items = new Items();
items.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that Items.js is loading before Phone.js

```
<script src="Items.js"></script>
<script src="Phone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like so:

```
var Items = new (function()
{
    this.stop = function()
    {
       // Items are hidden
       $(this.ButtonDiv).hide();
       $(this.CounterDiv).hide();
    }
})();
```

And call it like so:

```
Items.stop();
```